# JQuery Autocomplete Won't Render Results

Tags: jquery, django, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Trying to get a drop down!

Model:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    student_id = models.IntegerField()
    grade = models.IntegerField()
```

View:

```
def student_autocomplete(request):
    query = request.GET.get('term')
    if query:
        data = (Student.objects.filter(name__startswith = query).values('name', 'student_id', 'grade'))
        return JsonResponse(list(data), safe=False)
    else:
        data='blank'
        return JsonResponse(data)
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        console.log('ready!');
    });

    $("#student_auto").autocomplete({
    source: "{% url 'student-autocomplete' %}",
    minLength: 2,
    autoFocus: true,
    select: function (event, ui) {
        $('#student_auto').val( ui.item.name );
        console.log(ui, event);
    }
    });
    $("#student_auto").removeAttr("autocomplete").attr("autocomplete", "on");
```

I can see the data when I manually call the autocomplete url and it looks nice, but the results appear only as empty boxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't be a dunderhead - read the [docs](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)!

> An array of objects with label and value properties: [ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]

Which leads to:

```
def student_autocomplete(request):
    query = request.GET.get('term')
    results = []
    if query:
        data = Student.objects.filter(name__startswith = query).values()
        for d in data:
            d_json = {}
            d_json['value'] = d['name']
            d_json['id'] = d['student_id']
            results.append(d_json)
        return JsonResponse(results, safe=False)
    else:
        data ='blank'
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

For anyone else who is stuck: The value you want to autocomplete **should be labeled as value**. You can call any other value through `ui.item`.

Answer (score 0):

You need a success callback function, then map each list entry to your select like so:

```
     $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { term: request.term },
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data, function (i) {
                    return { label: i, value: i };
                }))
            }
        })
```